# Configure AutoMapper to return Mock in test layer

Tags: tdd, moq, automapper

In my app, all domain classes follow the standardization:

1. All implement the interface `IEntity`
2. `Id` properties are `protected`*
3. The properties of type `IList` are protected and initialized in the constructor.

Below is a classic example of a domain entity:

```
public class CheckListItemTemplate : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual CheckListItemTemplate Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CheckListItemTemplate> Itens { get; protected set; }

    public CheckListItemTemplate()
    {
        Itens = new List<CheckListItemTemplate>();
    }

    public void AddItem(CheckListItemTemplate item)
    {
        item.Parent = this;
        Itens.Add(item);
    }
}
```

> *This is because the id is generated by the database and not run the risk of some developer trying to set this property.

### Test project

We have a fake generic repository used in the tests:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    private readonly IDictionary<int, T> _context = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    public void Delete(T obj)
    {
        _context.Remove(obj.Id);
    }

    public void Store(T obj)
    {
        if (obj.Id > 0)
            _context[obj.Id] = obj;
        else
        {
            var generateId = _context.Values.Any() ? _context.Values.Max(p => p.Id) + 1 : 1;
            var stub = Mock.Get<T>(obj);
            stub.Setup(s => s.Id).Returns(generateId);
            _context.Add(generateId, stub.Object);
        }
    }

    // .. 
}
```

As you can see in the `Store`*, all test objects (of type `IEntity`) should be a `Mock`**. This is because in UI project, when we save an object NHibernate updating the property `Id`. In testing project we have to do this manually, and we have no way to set the property `Id` with a new value, so the solution was mock the entire object to the `Get` property `Id` correspond to the new Id . Exactly what does this line `stub.Setup(s => s.Id).Returns(generateId)`.

> *By convention, objects with Id <= 0 are new and Id> 0 are existing objects in the database.
>   **For Mock I use [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/).

### `Id` as protected

The biggest problem occurs because of `Id` property and the fact that is `protected`. 
When we talk about the designer, is a great approach but this brings huge inconvenience when we test our application.

For example, in a test that I'm writing I need my Fake repository with some data already populated.

### Code

Follow me. I have the following classes (+ `CheckListItemTemplate` shown above.)

```
public class Passo : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<CheckListItemTemplate> CheckListItens { get; protected set; }
}

public class Processo : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Passo Passo { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CheckListItem> CheckListItens { get; protected set; }
}
```

After saving the `Processo`, the first `Passo`  is associated with the `Processo`: (sorted by `Ordem` field following field `CreateAt`)

```
model.Passo = PassoRepositorio.All().OrderBy(p => p.Ordem).ThenBy(p => p.CreateAt).First();
model.CheckListItens.Clear();
Parallel.ForEach(Mapper.Map<IList<CheckListItem>>(model.Passo.CheckListItens), (it) => model.AddCheckListItem(it));
```

This code is running whenever you save a new `Processo`. For any test that creates a new `Processo`, this code will be executed!

#### Test

If we have to create a test that creates a new `Processo`, our first goal is to populate the `PassoRepositorio` repository with some dummy data*, with `Passos` and `CheckListItemTemplates` specifically for the above code does not fail**.

> *To populate objects with dummy data I use [AutoFixture](https://autofixture.codeplex.com/).
>   ** Will fail if no `Passo` is found in the repository `.First()` and this `Passo` has no checklist `Mapper.Map(model.Passo.CheckListItens)`.

---

So we need a repository of `Passos` and each `Passo` with a list of `CheckListItens`. 
Remember that every object `IEntity` should be an `Mock<>` so we can mock property `Id`

First attempt

First configure my `TestInitialize` to populate my repository with some dummy data:

```
var fix = new Fixture();
var listPassos = fix.Build<Mock<Passo>>()
                            .Do((passo) => {
                                passo.SetupProperty(x => x.Nome, fix.Create<string>());
                                passo.SetupGet(x => x.CheckListItens).Returns(
                                    fix.Build<CheckListItemTemplate>() // Needs to a Mock<>
                                        .With(p => p.Texto)
                                        .OmitAutoProperties()
                                        .CreateMany(5).ToList()
                                    );
                            })
                            .OmitAutoProperties()
                            .CreateMany(10);

foreach (var item in listPassos)
    passoRepository.Store(item.Object);
```

Then I can run the tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Salvar_novo_processo_modificar_data_atendimento_passo_atual()
{
    // Arrange
    var fix = new Fixture();
    var vm = fix.Create<ProcessoViewModel>();

    //Act
    Controller.salvar(vm); // Problem here. (For convert ProcessoViewModel to Processo I use a AutoMaper. In repository needs destination to be a Mock<Processo>
    var processo = Repository.Get(p => p.DataEntrada == vm.DataEntrada && p.ProximoAtendimento == vm.ProximoAtendimento);

    //Asserts
    processo.Should().NotBeNull();
    processo.Passo.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

## Questions

We create a list of 10 `Passo` where each `Passo` is actually is a `Mock<>`, great! But:

1. For each `Passo` have a list of 5 'Mock' items, and each `Id` should be 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 (in that order). How to achieve this? How to obtain this list of `IList<Mock<>>` inside a `Mock<>` with `Id` already filled? That is, the configuration
   `passo.SetupGet(x => x.CheckListItens).Returns( ???`
2. The responsible for creating objects in my controller, basically uses AutoMapper to convert my ViewModel object to an object that can be persisted Model in my repository:
   `model = Mapper.Map<TModel>(vm);`
   The problem is that my repository Fake can not save an object `IEntity`, just `Mock<IEntity>`. How to configure AutoMapper to always return a `Mock<>`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether all the content of this question is relevant to the actual questions at the end. Also, you're posting two questions here rather than one. It would have been useful if you could try and reduce the size of the problem down to something much smaller!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Question 1: In case this helps, you can use a closure to maintain a running counter to use as an id. For example:

```cs
class MyTestClass
{
  int _runningCounter = 0;

  public void SomeTest()
  {
    /* ... some other code including mock creation ...*/

    someMock.Setup(m => m.ReturnNewWidgetEntity())
      .Returns(() => new WidgetEntity{ Id= ++_runningCounter });
  }
}
```

Each time `ReturnNewWidgetEntity` is called on the mocked object, the Id property will be set to an increased number.

Answer for Question 2: I would suggest that rather than having a concrete dependency on the `Mapper` class, you replace this with an injected dependency on `IMapperEngine`. Richard Dingwall explains the technique here: http://richarddingwall.name/2009/05/07/mocking-out-automapper-with-dependency-injection/

Basically you register `Mapper.Engine` as the singleton implementation of `IMapperEngine` in your container and then in your unit tests mock it so that it gives you the required `Mock<>` classes.

I hope one or both of these answers at least give you food for thought. It was a bit difficult to follow your whole example, to be honest!